# Why doesn't `hg diff` show the complete diff?

Tags: mercurial, terminal, diff

I just added 16 lines of code, but `hg diff` is only showing the first four lines.  If I do

```
hg diff > huh.txt
```

I can see the complete diff in the `huh.txt` file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but doing a

```
reset
```

in my terminal session, I again see the complete diff.